# Is there a non-default alternative for Properties.Settings.Default?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In ASP.NET, when you want to reference application settings, you use the **Properties.Settings** object. Immediately after that, there is a **Default** object which contains all the application settings.

My question is: Is there a way to have something other than that Default profile in **Properties.Settings.Default**? Something like a custom non-default area for settings. I have a web application that has lots of modules and each one has a bunch of settings relevant only to that module. I'm looking for a way to keep them separated.

The closest thing I've found is this SO question ([Using Properties.Settings.Default and Setting Alternate Profiles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11655378/using-properties-settings-default-and-setting-alternate-profiles)), but it wasn't really the answer I expected and I wanted to give it another shot and see if anyone had discovered something new.

**Edit:** This MSDN document explains EXACTLY what I want (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397748%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). However it's just not working for me. The supposed Settings File type doesn't exist.

Comment: Could you not add settings to each module (presumably a class library/project)?

Comment: I'm trying to find out if it's possible to have something like **Properties.Settings.SomethingElseOtherThanDefault** which I'm sure exists because, why use the Default object to hold the settings instead of puttin gthem straight into the Settings object?

Comment: This MSDN document explains EXACTLY what I want (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397748%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). However it's just not working for me. The supposed Settings File type doesn't exist. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

Could you create extra web.config files and use the [WebConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.aspx) to read from the appropriate config file?

**Edit:** Sorry, I had originally said CongurationManager you will want WebConfigurationManager.

Comment: I've used that method in past projects. However using WebConfigurationManager requires previous knowledge of the names of the settings because they need to be entered as a string key. I'm particularly interested in Properties.Settings because it creates strongly typed objects for each setting.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant "I want to create my own *section*" (of settings)

- see [How To create Custom Config Sections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).
- if you choose, you can it further and create separate `MyCustomSettings.config` *files* , e.g. `<pages configSource="pages.config"/>` see [`configSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: No, I know about the additional config sections. But I'm really interested in using the Properties.Settings object in particular. I believe the guy who posted the question I referenced was onto something when he was digging into the xml of that object and he found something about "profiles".